# Toggling between two different stylesheets

Tags: jquery, toggle, stylesheet

I am trying to toggle between two different stylesheets to display different theme styles.
I have 2 different stylesheets that I want to toggle between.

The stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="light" href="css/default.css" />
<link rel="alternative stylesheet" type="text/css" title="dark" href="css/default_style2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
```

I gave each stylesheet a title tag of light and dark for reference when the toggle will be clicked to change the stylesheets.

my jQuery code:

```
<div id="toggleTheme">

        <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#light, #dark").click(function () {
                changeStyle(this.getAttribute("rel"));
                return false;
            });

            function changeStyle (light, dark) {

                var light = $(this).attr('title') == "light";
                var dark = $(this).attr('title') == "dark";

                if ()
            }

        });

        </script>

        <ul id="themeToggle">

        <a href="#" id="light"><li>light theme</li></a>
        <a href="#" id="dark"><li>dark theme</li></a>

        </ul>

        </div>
```

Not sure where to go from here...

Some assistance will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't change the file.. change the class of the document to preview. If you need to use a different file I suggest a post and reload the page with the appropriate style.

Answer (score 2):

Simply [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach) the one you don't want to be applied. The browser will remove all of the styles it defines. To activate it, attach it and detach the other one.

Here's a ***very*** quick and dirty example using `style` elements, but the same principle applies to `link` elements:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Changing styles</title>
  <style id="light">
    body {
      color: black;
      background-color: white;
    }
  </style>
  <style id="dark">
    body {
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <label><input type="radio" name="chooseStyle" value="light">Light</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="chooseStyle" value="dark" checked>Dark</label>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var styles = {
        light: $("#light").detach(),
        dark:  $("#dark")
      };

      $("input[name=chooseStyle]").click(function() {
        var other = this.value === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
        styles[this.value].appendTo('head');
        styles[other].detach();
      });
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/aduYodEz/1)

Comment: Thanks for this. Works very nicely and simple. Just not sure how to apply your example to my scenario.

Comment: @user3040525: What aren't you sure of? Again, your `link` elements are just like my `style` elements. You have something that triggers your code to switch between stylesheets; so do I.